# How can I create a deb from binaries?

Tags: packaging, deb

I have a few binary files: foo, bar.so, and foo.lnk. I want to make a deb that will extract foo to `/usr/share/foo/foo`, bar to that same directory, and foo.lnk to `/usr/share/applications`. I dont want to include any source and there are a few dependencies that I need to make sure are installed.

I've found some resources such as http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html and https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging . The problem is that they are guides meant to include the source. Furthermore, I really dont understand how I specify where to extract certain files to.

Answer (score 2):

I found a relatively simple way to do it, all that's missing from that are how to run the pre-install and post-install scripts. (And if there's a way to add an uninstall script).

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717

1. Decide on the name of your package. Standard Debian notation is all lowercase in the following format:

   ```
   <project>_<major version>.<minor version>-<package revision>
   ```

   For example, you could name your first package...

   ```
   helloworld_1.0-1
   ```
2. Create a directory to make your package in. The name should be the same as the package name.

   ```
   mkdir helloworld_1.0-1
   ```
3. Pretend that the packaging directory is actually the root of the file system. Put the files of your program where they would be installed to on a system.

   ```
   mkdir helloworld_1.0-1/usr  
   mkdir helloworld_1.0-1/usr/local  
   mkdir helloworld_1.0-1/usr/local/bin  
   cp "~/Projects/Hello World/helloworld" helloworld_1.0-1/usr/local/bin
   ```
4. Now create a special metadata file with which the package manager will install your program.

   ```
   mkdir helloworld_1.0-1/DEBIAN  
   gedit helloworld_1.0-1/DEBIAN/control
   ```

   Put something like this in that file.

   ```
   Package: helloworld
   Version: 1.0-1
   Section: base
   Priority: optional
   Architecture: i386
   Depends: libsomethingorrather (>= 1.2.13), anotherDependency (>= 1.2.6)
   Maintainer: Your Name <you@email.com>
   Description: Hello World
    When you need some sunshine, just run this
    small program!
   ```

   The space before each line in the description is important.
5. Now you just need to make the package:

   ```
   dpkg-deb --build helloworld_1.0-1
   ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.